# cakephp pre-fill email form with address

Tags: forms, email, cakephp

I have a list of email addresses on a page and I would like to add the functionality so that when an email address is clicked it opens up an email form with that email address already pre-filled in the recipient field. How can I do this?

This is the form I have already;

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Email', array('action'=>'email_send.php'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'To: ')); //i want the email address i clicked on to be automatically placed here.
    echo $this->Form->input('message',array('type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Message: '));
echo $this->Form->end('Send'); ?>
```

Also if anyone has any tips on how I'll structure the email_send.php file and the best way to pass variables and perform validation I could use a hand with that too.

Comment: do the emails come from a database, or are they hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cake, you could achieve it a little like this.. obviously improvements can be made but it's an example:

#### EmailsController.php (controller)

```
function list_emails() {
    $this->set('emails', $this->EmailModel->find('all', array('fields' => 
                                                         array('id', 'email'))));

}
```

#### list_emails.ctp (view)

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($emails as $email) {
   echo '<li>' . $this->Html->link('Email: ' . $email['EmailModel']['email'],
          array('action'=>'process', $email['EmailModel']['id'])) . '</li>'; ?>
}
// generates a list of emails in the format:
// <a href="emails/process/1">Email: foo@foo.com</a>
echo '</ul>';
```

#### EmailsController.php (controller)

```
function process($email_id = null) {
    if(!$email_id) { 
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'show_emails')); // no id specified 
    }
    // check if the form has been submit, otherwise, get the info for the view..

    $this->EmailModel->id = $email_id;
    $email = $this->EmailModel->read();
    $this->set('email', $email);   
}
```

and the information is now available to you in your `process` view.

```
// echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'To: ','value'=>$email['EmailModel']['email']));
```

but it's a lot of work really. And don't forget the value can be always be changed; making this a bit pointless

Comment: Fabulous. Much appreciated thank you for the well-explained answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

in controller

```
$this->set('email',$email); //$email is the mail address from database
```

in view

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'To: ','value'=>$email));
```

or

you can put email in '$this->request->data' array it will automatically populate in view like this:
you should add this in your controller

```
$this->request->data['Email']['email'] = 'YOUR_EMAIL_FROM_DATABASE';
```